# Mac OS X - Big TV windows too big

Tags: macos, mac, display, resolution

i have a 1920x1080 tv and i have my mac going into it. Since it is a 32", windows and the dock are large, and a lot of room is wasted. I understand this is what a high res screen is for. Like the apple Thunderbolt Display. But i was just wondering if there is any applications that can solve/reduce my problems matters.
Thanks in advance.
Josh

Comment: Have you turned off screen mirroring and checked that the resolution sent to the tv is correct in display preferences?

Comment: The res is correct(1920x1080), and yeah so is mirroring, the display is clear, its just i would like a bit more real estate on that monitor.

Answer (score 0):

In the System Preferences Panel, under Displays, select the Scaled option, and pick your resolution (1080i).  The TVs I've connected to, I've had to move the Underscan slider one notch to the right, so that my menu bar and screen borders would appear.  This assumes you're using an HDMI connection.